# Looking for a way to change change a navigation block in a Category Page

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, custom, ee-1.13.0.1

I want to be able to change our hallwines.com/shop page layout when going to a category page that will be say, http://www.hallwines.com/shop-wine-gifts so that I can have a custom Navigation side bar that will only show on this category page. I have a block setup to replace it in the the "Custom Layout" just not clear on how to call it and the code to stop the regular Shop Side bar from showing? Any help would be greatly appreciated, perhaps even a bottle of wine in it for you, and we make really good wine!

thanks much

Mbuckley@hallwines.com

Comment: show your code ?

Comment: I don't really have code ready. Just want to take this landing page > http://www.hallwines.com/shop-wine-gifts and instead of showing the "SHOP HALL" Block, I want it to show this new Block in it's place. Block Identifier "shop_hall_gift_nav_bar" and Widget ID 19 Here is my setup of the Widget, thinking it might not be correct, but if it is, how do I call it in the "Custom Layout Update" https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecc94x3i5yek258/WidgetSetup.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 steps

1. Remove layered navigation from a specific category
2. Add your custom block (I suppose it is a static block)

In Admin > Catalog > Manage categories > [your_specific_category] > Custom Design Tab > Custom Layout Update :

```
<reference name="right">

    <!-- Step 1 : Remove layered navigation -->
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />

    <!-- Step 2 : Add your custom static block -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="your_block" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block</block_id></action>
    </block> 

</reference>
```

Comment: Or `<reference name="left">`, depending on your design. Also, better to use `<remove/>` for the nav block to save processing power.

Comment: @benmarks: i updated my answer with <remove />

Comment: Interesting. I do want to keep the main layout shown here (from source code) > <div class="main col2-right-layout">
            <div class="col-main"> - but change the block that shows in this party of the layout > <div class="col-right sidebar">

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't do anything >

Comment: If Step 1 doesn't work it's because the block name (catalog.leftnav) isn't the good one. If you find the good block name it should work. About Step 2, did you replace "your_block" with your block name (shop_hall_gift_nav_bar) ?